# Access token request format for google plus in C# web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_id=2411apps.googleusercontent.com& client_secret=DE8edtObypGBB&code=4/cCm5zsrhdCjielw01sQ0ZXE-sT2ZLcbTxpyrGgAI& redirect_uri=http://mydomain.com/socialauth/validate.sauth&grant_type=authorization_code
```

This is the request url sent to google plus server to get access token. But it returns 405 method no permitted error. In documentation they mentioned the access token request like

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1    
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
redirect_uri=ttps://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/code&
sgrant_type=authorization_code
```

Is there any specific format to send a request for access token? Also I am facing the problem for soundcloud also. I am using HttpWebRequest to give a request. I went through previously asked questions related to this. But nothing is working fine. Could any one give a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, your first URL looks like a GET request with URL arguments. The example references a POST request with body arguments. Is the issue that you cannot send a POST request from HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Not with POST. Initially I used GET request with URL arguments. I tried with examples from stackoverflow previous questions related to this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833281/how-to-get-access-token-for-google-oauth) . I am using HttpWebRequest to send a request. If any other workaround for POST request with body arguments, give me. Major problem is i don't know how to send the parameters in body in any other way. Thanks for ur reply.

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833281/how-to-get-access-token-for-google-oauth) Solution in this link throws error that no arguments in body.